# Dynamically arranging divs using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="someid1" style="float:right"></div>
<div id="someid2" style="float:right"></div>
<div id="someid3" style="float:right"></div>
<div id="someid4" style="float:right"></div>
</div>
```

Now someid is acually a unique id for that div. Now i receive an array which has a different order say someid 3,2,1,4, then how do i move these divs around to match the new order using jQuery?

Thankyou very much for your time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My plugin version - **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/ihuqo)**

Takes an array and optional id prefix and reorders elements whose ids correspond to the order of (id prefix) + values inside the array. Any values in the array that don't have an element with the corresponding id will be ignored, and any child elements that do not have an id within the array will be removed.

```
(function($) {

$.fn.reOrder = function(array, prefix) {
  return this.each(function() {
    prefix = prefix || "";

    if (array) {    
      for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++) 
        array[i] = $('#' + prefix + array[i]);

      $(this).empty();  

      for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++)
        $(this).append(array[i]);      
    }
  });    
}
})(jQuery);
```

Code from the demo

**jQuery**

```
 $(function() {
  $('#go').click(function() {

    var order = $('#order').val() == ""? null: $('#order').val().split(",");
    $('#container').reOrder(order, 'someid');
  });
});

(function($) {

$.fn.reOrder = function(array, prefix) {
  return this.each(function() {
    prefix = prefix || "";

    if (array) {    
      for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++) 
        array[i] = $('#' + prefix + array[i]);

      $(this).empty();  

      for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++)
        $(this).append(array[i]);      
    }
  });    
}
})(jQuery);
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>reOrder Demo</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body { background-color: #fff; font: 16px Helvetica, Arial; color: #000; }
div.style { width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #000000; margin: 5px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="someid1" class="style" style="background-color:green;">div1</div>
<div id="someid2" class="style" style="background-color:blue;">div2</div>
<div id="someid3" class="style" style="background-color:red;">div3</div>
<div id="someid4" class="style" style="background-color:purple;">div4</div>
</div>
<p>Pass in a comma separated list of numbers 1-4 to reorder divs</p>
<input id="order" type="text" />
<input id="go" type="button" value="Re-Order" />


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent.  I just used this to have a "plus / minus" ordering system on a list of li's.  Adapted wonderfully.

Comment: A nice update would be a way to hide any that aren't shown in one pass, but have them survive to show again in a second call. e.g., pass 1,2; then pass 3,4. I was working on a slider and used an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4649595/292060; but this is a nice general purpose answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Edit], This is tested and works:

```
var order = [3,2,1,4];
var container = $("#container");
var children = container.children();
container.empty();
for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++){
    container.append(children[order[i]-1])
}
```

The i-1 is necessary since your ordering starts at 1 but arrays are indexed from 0.

Thanks to J-P and Russ Cam for making me look at it again.

Comment: In your loop, the 'i' value will just be 0, 1, 2, 3 and not the values from the order array. Instead, you need container.append(children[order[i]-1]);
Feel free to test here: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#jquery

Comment: It's bad practice to use for-in loops in regular arrays.

Comment: @Gabriel - the code doesn't reorder the divs as I believe var children holds references to the same elements that get removed then appended. That's why they need to be cloned

Comment: @J-P you're correct, that was a bad idea since javascript arrays don't know how to count ;-). It was 4 AM.
@Russ Cam the elements don't need to be cloned. They persist in the "children" variable after emptying the container. Tested and working.

Comment: @Gabriel - right you are. For some reason, it didn't seem to be working for me without the clone yesterday, but quite obviously does. Must have been something else.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jQuery-less solution:

```
function appendNodesById(parent, ids) {
    for(var i = 0, len = ids.length; i < len; ++i)
        parent.appendChild(document.getElementById(ids[i]));
}

appendNodesById(document.getElementById('container'),
    ['someid4', 'someid2', 'someid3', 'someid1']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the content in the array then remove all the content from the wrapper div *container* in your code. then start adding the received divs one by one:

```
 var v = $(ar[0]).append(ar[1]).append(ar[2]);
 $("#container").html(v);
```

If this does not works then look into [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158070/jquery-how-to-position-one-element-relative-to-another) that discusses about positioning elements relative to other elements.