# Sort order of table tbody in same order as list elments jquery json

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have been working on this jsFiddle and wanted to extend the functionality so that when the list items have been altered and submitted via the form then the associated table tbodys sort themselves in the same order as their list item counterparts:

http://jsfiddle.net/8vWXZ/20/

Is it possible to map the order from one element to another like this in jQuery?

I am not fussed about things animating but this new requirement has thrown me somewhat.

Comment: I have tried to solve this and updated the jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8vWXZ/22/

The plugin i am trying to use is located here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929519/dynamically-arranging-divs-using-jquery/929607#929607

But it does not want to play ball for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get what the ajax call was supposed to do, so I skipped that part. But the logic for resorting the table according to the list order is there, on the submit action of the form. I also reorganized how the `tbody` tag was used, since it didn't really serve a purpose to have each `tr` inside their own `tbody` tag.

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8vWXZ/24/

The code, to have it here on SO:
*(`#tableOrder` is the table whose `tr`s we are to reorder according to the order of the `li`s inside of `ul#reOrder`)*

```
 $('#frmItems').submit(function() {

    var tbl = $("#tableOrder tbody");

    $("#reOrder li").each(function(index) {
        var li_id = $(this).attr("id");
        //Find the number of the item. Eg "item4" should result in "4"
        var li_item_number = li_id.match(/item([0-9]*)/)[1];
        //Inside #tableOrder, find the element (a <tr>) with id corresponding the this <li>'s id. Eg "item4"'s corresponding table row's id is "#tbl-item4"
        var correspondingTR = tbl.find("#tbl-item" + li_item_number);

        tbl.append(correspondingTR);
    });
```

I also did one more modifications. You had given both your `li` elements and `tr` elements the same ids (eg `item1`), which was bad ([mmkay](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4_tOiLB_Ko)), since an ID should be unique. So i changed the `tr`s inside `tableOrder` to have ids `tbl-item1` and so on.

`li_id.match(/item([0-9]*)/)[1]` is a [regex](http://www.google.com/search?q=regular+expression) match. Basically, it searches for a pattern in the string and we can draw sertain sections out of that string. What it looks for is the pattern inside the slashes, so it's looking for something like `itemX` where `X` is a number (`[0-9]` says we are interested in any number from 0 to 9). It will return an array, and the item on index `1` is the number we are interested in.

About the `append`:
The `.each` goes through the `li`s, which are in the *correct* order. For each one, it adds the corresponding `tr` to the *end* of the table. Because all the `tr`s in the table will be "touched", this means that it builds the order of the `tr`s from scratch. The first `tr` to be appended, is the one on the top. The last one to be appended is the one on the bottom (as in, `tr` on spot *n* is appended in iteration *n*)
I made two demos whose usefulnes is questionable, but you may find them helpful. http://jsfiddle.net/bGGRT/ and http://jsfiddle.net/bGGRT/1/

Comment: That's great.  Thank you.

Could i trouble you to comment it a bit as well?

I don't understand this:

var li_id = $(this).attr("id").match("item([0-9]*)")[1];

Or how the append is working here either?

Comment: Sorry the AJAX call was for something else so you were right to ignore.

Comment: Updated :) Adding comment about the append in a bit

Comment: Thanks yes i understood IDs have to be unique but it was only a POC.