# JQuery (Javascript) / CSS, way to rearrange order of elements within DIV without using positioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm a bit unsure of how to do this. I have a main panel where I want to display a DIV in that based on an action. I have the DIVS laid out like this in the html:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="1"></div>
   <div id="2"></div>
</div>
```

Rather than messing around with positioning, I want to make it so that when something happens I can just put div id=2 above div id=1, as simply as possible. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: So when you said above did you mean the z-index, or above in sequential layout order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the example you are showing you can simply use the `append`, and `prepend` jquery methods.

For example, div#1 then div#2

```
$('#container').append('#1').append('#2');
```

Reorder, div#2 then div#1

```
$('#container #2').remove().prependTo('#container');
```

There are many ways you could write this. Just remember `prepend` places an element at the beginning (before the first element) of the container, while `append` places the element after the last element.

Comment: @torazaburo - The question was tagged with jQuery by the OP. This answer was accepted as the correct answer by the OP. This question is also over 2 years old. Since you don't seem to understand down-voting read up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down).

Answer (score 1):

You simply do this absolute positioning the divs. If something happens, just set z-index of the elements.
For example (using simple JS):

```
var d1 = document.getElementById('1');
var d2 = document.getElementById('2');

d1.style.zIndex = 1;
d2.style.zIndex = 2;
```

If you want to update them, just reset the zIndex ;)

Comment: ah ok so they can just be on top of each other then.. I'm kinda rusty on my CSS so didn't realize this

Comment: Yes! With absolute positioning sure! Or maybe if you just want to show/hide the divs you can use d1.style.display = "none" and/or d2.style.display = "block".
If you just want to switch the DOM elements, you can use some jQuery methods to change their order! (like Josiah Ruddell wrote)

Comment: ahh I don't think I can use absolute positioning for what I'm trying to do, will have to try the other way of doing it

Comment: Ok, np, you can easily switch the elements with jQuery :) ..OR.. if you want to test and/or try another framework (i.e. mootools) look at this great example by david walsh: http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/mootools-swap.php

Answer (score 0):

remove the second element and reinsert it before the first element.

javascript:

```
var d1 = document.getElementById('1');
var d2 = document.getElementById('2');

d2.parentNode.removeChild(d2);
d1.parentNode.insertBefore(d2, d1);
​
```