# Re-ordering divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, sql-order-by

Is it possible to re-order some divs with jQuery. I have few divs and I would like re-order them on page load according data-index number that is in divs.

Now:

```
<div class="score" data-index="3">3</div>
<div class="score" data-index="2">2</div>
<div class="score" data-index="1">1</div>
<div class="score" data-index="4">4</div>
```

What I want:

```
<div class="score" data-index="1">1</div>
<div class="score" data-index="2">2</div>
<div class="score" data-index="3">3</div>
<div class="score" data-index="4">4</div>
```

I believe this should be possible with jQuery. I go each div and get the data-index number but how do I do the actual ordering :D

Thx!

EDIT: one thing is that the order in HTML can vary on each page load (the order can 3,2,1,4 or 4,1,3,2 or anything).

And this is the only JS I have now:

```
$("html .score").each(function(index, domEle) {
            var score = $(domEle).attr("data-index");
            alert(score);
        });
```

Just gets data-index number alerts it.

Comment: Can you show the code you've already tried? SO is not a community-code-generator. ;)

Comment: This might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929519/dynamically-arranging-divs-using-jquery

Answer (score 12):

HTML

```
<div class="sortable">
    <div class="score" data-index="3">3</div>
    <div class="score" data-index="2">2</div>
    <div class="score" data-index="1">1</div>
    <div class="score" data-index="4">4</div>
</div>
```

jQuery 
---------ascending

```
$('.sortable').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.append($this.find('.score').get().sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).data('index') - $(b).data('index');
    }));
});
```

---------descending

```
$('.sortable').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.append($this.find('.score').get().sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(b).data('index') - $(a).data('index');
    }));
});
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/RyEQU/)

Comment: no need of .each here,
    `$('.sortable').append($('.score').sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).data('index') - $(b).data('index');
    }));`

Comment: @Chamika Sandamal: I added each as a feature, so the OP can use it on any element of the same class. But of course, that can be taken away.

Answer (score 2):

```
function sortDivs(a,b){  
    return $(a).data("index") > $(b).data("index") ? 1 : -1;  
};  


$(".score").sort(sortDivs).appendTo($("#results"));
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ahsAD/3/)

Comment: `$(a).data("index") > $(b).data("index") ? 1 : -1;`

Comment: thanks, improved upon according to your comment, hadn't used the data method before.