# Ordering divs with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have `<div>`s nested inside a main `<div>`.

The main `<div>` has the `class="data"` attribute and the nested `<div>`s have a `class="smallData"` attribute.

Inside of the *.smallData* `<div>`s there is a `<span>` which is updated by jQuery. This value is a *rating*.

I want to now order the `<div>`s after a rating has increased/decreased so that they are always in ascending order. Everything I have tried doesn't seem to 
work. Here is my code:

```
<div class="data" id="entries">
{% for entry in entries %}
<div class="smallData" >
    <div id="entryHead">
        <h3>{{ entry.name }} </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="entryBody">
        <p><b>Rating: <span id="spanText" class="rate_{{ entry.key.id()}}">{{ entry.rating }}</span></b><br><b>likes: <span class="like_{{ entry.key.id()}}">{{ entry.likes }}</span> dislikes: <span class="dislike_{{ entry.key.id()}}">{{ entry.dislikes }}</span></b></p>
        <p><a href="javascript:likes('{{entry.key.id()}}');" >Like</a>  | <a href="javascript:dislikes('{{entry.key.id()}}');" >Dislike</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

This produces `<div>`'s for each entity in my database. The code that updates the rating looks like this:

```
function dislikes(entryKey){
        // Update the datastore by passing a json object to python script. Return field dislikes when complete
        var name = "dislike_" + entryKey;
        var rate = "rate_" + entryKey;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/dislike/",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ "entryKey": entryKey})
        })
            // Run this function when the datastore update is complete
                .done(function( data ) { // check why I use done
                    $('.' + name).text(data[0]);
                    $('.' + rate).text(data[1]);
                });
    }
```

I want my order to update after the ratings have been updated. So in other words every time the link is clicked the order must be checked to see if it is correct.

Comment: you need to show us what you tried, not tell us it didn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Re-ordering divs with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137804/re-ordering-divs-with-jquery)

Comment: I tried the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137804/re-ordering-divs-with-jquery) question but it did not help me. I have updated the question to include my code and explained a bit more on what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes three steps:

1. Detach the `smallData` items from the DOM and store in an array
2. [Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the HTML elements by rating (making sure to do an [integer comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#wikiArticle))
3. Append the results back into the main `<div>`

You could write this in one line of jQuery, but here's a runnable example that is slightly more verbose:

```js
$("#reorder").on("click", function() {
  //detach the smallData divs from the DOM
  var smallDatas = $(".data .smallData").detach().toArray(); 
  
  //sort the HTML elements by rating (make sure to do an integer comparison)
  smallDatas.sort(function(a,b) {
    return parseInt($(a).find(".rating").text(), 10) > parseInt($(b).find(".rating").text(), 10);
  });
  
  //append the results back into the main div
  $(".data").append(smallDatas);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">
  <div class="smallData">
    <span class="rating">100</span>
  </div>
  <div class="smallData">
    <span class="rating">40</span>
  </div>
  <div class="smallData">
    <span class="rating">20</span>
  </div>
  <div class="smallData">
    <span class="rating">10</span>
  </div>
  <div class="smallData">
    <span class="rating">5</span>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="reorder">reorder</button>
```

Comment: Do we know the ratings are integers? They may be floats.

Comment: This was extremely helpful! Thanks! The only thing i had to change for my code was the `.find(".rating")`. I had to change mine to `.find("#rating")` as I was referring to an id instead of a class. I also took the `$("#reorder").on("click", ` away and named the function update() and called it each time a rating was increased or decreased. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelRichardson FYI you shouldn't have multiple items on the page with the same ID. Also, if this answer helped you, please accept it using the `✔` underneath the voting buttons.