# Sorting Images by File Name

Tags: jquery, image

I want help arranging images. I have this table and I want the images to appear in a certain order, eg B A G D.... (going from left to right).

The code can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kommandoss/YuRpU/39/).

Comment: How will you identify the order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/929607/295264). This is what you might be asking.

I create a perfect modification of that function for you

```
function sorter(selector, order) {
    selector.each(function() {
        if(order) {
            for(var i =0; i < order.length; i++){                     
               $("#sorted").append($(this).children('img[id='+order[i]+']'));                
            }
        }

    });
}
sorter($("div"), ['a','c','d']);
```

[Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/YuRpU/50/)

Comment: is there a way of not putting it in an array?

Comment: @user1259527, array is to define the order. And thats because you will have to define that array somehow and no matter what array will be end type of whatever pre-format you use. So, stick with this.

Comment: @user1259527, I updated a function perfect for you case. You should be able to make necessary changes to it now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty way to do it by simply using `appendTo()` to rearrange the `img`s:

```
var order = ['b', 'a', 'g', 'd', 'h', 'c', 'i', 'f', 'e'];

$('img').parent().each(function(x) {
    $('#'+order[x]).appendTo($(this));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/HFu7j/

And, I've said it before, but you should really consider getting rid of your inline javascript.  Inline code is outdated and makes code maintenance and debug a lot more difficult.  Use event binding in jQuery instead, such as with `.on()`.

Answer (score -1):

Just re-arrange your code in the order you want them to flow.  For example:

```
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hydrattz/multipurpose-alphabet/128/Letter-A-dg-icon.png" ondragstart="drag(event);" id="a" draggable="true"/>
        </div>
    </td>
   <td>
        <div ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hydrattz/multipurpose-alphabet/128/Letter-B-dg-icon.png"  ondragstart="drag(event);" id="b" draggable="true"/> </div>
    </td>
   <td>
        <div ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hydrattz/multipurpose-alphabet/128/Letter-C-dg-icon.png"  ondragstart="drag(event);" id="c" draggable="true"/> </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <div ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hydrattz/multipurpose-alphabet/128/Letter-D-dg-icon.png"  ondragstart="drag(event);" id="d" draggable="true"/> </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hydrattz/multipurpose-alphabet/128/Letter-F-dg-icon.png"  ondragstart="drag(event);" id="f" draggable="true"/> </div>
    </td>
   <td>
        <div ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hydrattz/multipurpose-alphabet/128/Letter-G-dg-icon.png"  ondragstart="drag(event);" id="g" draggable="true"/> </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <div ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hydrattz/multipurpose-alphabet/128/Letter-H-dg-icon.png"  ondragstart="drag(event);" id="h" draggable="true"/> </div>
    </td>
   <td>
        <div ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hydrattz/multipurpose-alphabet/128/Letter-I-dg-icon.png"  ondragstart="drag(event);" id="i" draggable="true"/> </div>
    </td>
  <td>
```

Would become

```
 <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hydrattz/multipurpose-alphabet/128/Letter-B-dg-icon.png" ondragstart="drag(event);" id="b" draggable="true"/>
        </div>
    </td>
   <td>
        <div ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hydrattz/multipurpose-alphabet/128/Letter-A-dg-icon.png"  ondragstart="drag(event);" id="a" draggable="true"/> </div>
    </td>
   <td>
        <div ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hydrattz/multipurpose-alphabet/128/Letter-G-dg-icon.png"  ondragstart="drag(event);" id="g" draggable="true"/> </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <div ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hydrattz/multipurpose-alphabet/128/Letter-D-dg-icon.png"  ondragstart="drag(event);" id="d" draggable="true"/> </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hydrattz/multipurpose-alphabet/128/Letter-F-dg-icon.png"  ondragstart="drag(event);" id="f" draggable="true"/> </div>
    </td>
   <td>
        <div ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hydrattz/multipurpose-alphabet/128/Letter-C-dg-icon.png"  ondragstart="drag(event);" id="c" draggable="true"/> </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <div ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hydrattz/multipurpose-alphabet/128/Letter-H-dg-icon.png"  ondragstart="drag(event);" id="h" draggable="true"/> </div>
    </td>
   <td>
        <div ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hydrattz/multipurpose-alphabet/128/Letter-I-dg-icon.png"  ondragstart="drag(event);" id="i" draggable="true"/> </div>
    </td>
  <td>
```

Comment: yes but I would like a button that does this, I was thinking of adding a refresh button but this isint really the way it should be done

Comment: At the very least, the inline JavaScript should be eliminated.

Comment: @Sparky672 Apologies, I needed to research and use trial and error to get the answer I got.  I didn't know about the inline.  Thank you for editing my answer.