# JavaScript append div contents in another Div and sort the contents based on the Rank order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have HTML codes like below.

When "Click" is clicked, the parent (div class="studentRow" ref="xxxx") is appended in the (div id="favoriteListContent").

The Rank text may contain some letters. The rank should be sorted using only number. If the Rank value is NO, this should be listed last - lowest rank.

How can I sort the sets of divs based on the Rank value in the (div id="favoriteListContent")?  Right now, the divs are displayed in the order they are clicked. (see **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/sunflowersh/YeSvH/11/)

```
<h2>Favorites</h2>
<div id="favoritesList">    
<div class="studentRow">
    <div class="favRow1"></div>
    <div class="positionRow1">Rank</div>
    <div class="studentRow1">Name</div>
    <div class="todayRow1">Today</div>
    <div class="thruRow1">Thru</div>
    <div class="totalRow1">Total</div>
</div>
<div id="favoriteListContent"></div>
</div>

<div id="studentList">
<h2>List</h2>
<div class="studentRow" ref="1000">
    <div class="favRow1" ref="1000">click</div>
    <div class="positionRow1">1</div>
    <div class="studentRow1">Name A</div>
    <div class="todayRow1">-3</div>
    <div class="thruRow1">F</div>
    <div class="totalRow1">-9</div>
</div>
<div class="studentRow" ref="2000">
    <div class="favRow2" ref="2000">click</div>
    <div class="positionRow2">D2</div>
    <div class="studentRow2">Name B</div>
    <div class="todayRow2">-2</div>
    <div class="thruRow2">F</div>
    <div class="totalRow2">-7</div>
</div>
<div class="studentRow" ref="1050">
    <div class="favRow1" ref="1050">click</div>
    <div class="positionRow1">D2</div>
    <div class="studentRow1">Name C</div>
    <div class="todayRow1">A</div>
    <div class="thruRow1">F</div>
    <div class="totalRow1">-7</div>
</div>
<div class="studentRow" ref="1800">
    <div class="favRow2" ref="1800">click</div>
    <div class="positionRow2">NO</div>
    <div class="studentRow2">Name H</div>
    <div class="todayRow2"></div>
    <div class="thruRow2"></div>
    <div class="totalRow2">+19</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to have the end result to be like

```
<h2>Favorites</h2>
<div id="favoritesList">    
<div class="studentRow">
    <div class="favRow1"></div>
    <div class="positionRow1">Rank</div>
    <div class="studentRow1">Name</div>
    <div class="todayRow1">Today</div>
    <div class="thruRow1">Thru</div>
    <div class="totalRow1">Total</div>
</div>
<div id="favoriteListContent">
<div class="studentRow" ref="1000">
    <div class="favRow1" ref="1000">click</div>
    <div class="positionRow1">1</div>
    <div class="studentRow1">Name A</div>
    <div class="todayRow1">-3</div>
    <div class="thruRow1">F</div>
    <div class="totalRow1">-9</div>
</div>
<div class="studentRow" ref="2000">
    <div class="favRow2" ref="2000">click</div>
    <div class="positionRow2">D2</div>
    <div class="studentRow2">Name B</div>
    <div class="todayRow2">-2</div>
    <div class="thruRow2">F</div>
    <div class="totalRow2">-7</div>
</div>
<div class="studentRow" ref="1800">
    <div class="favRow2" ref="1800">click</div>
    <div class="positionRow2">NO</div>
    <div class="studentRow2">Name H</div>
    <div class="todayRow2"></div>
    <div class="thruRow2"></div>
    <div class="totalRow2">+19</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and Not

```
<div class="studentRow" ref="1800">
    <div class="favRow2" ref="1800">click</div>
    <div class="positionRow2">NO</div>
    <div class="studentRow2">Name H</div>
    <div class="todayRow2"></div>
    <div class="thruRow2"></div>
    <div class="totalRow2">+19</div>
</div>
<div class="studentRow" ref="2000">
    <div class="favRow2" ref="2000">click</div>
    <div class="positionRow2">D2</div>
    <div class="studentRow2">Name B</div>
    <div class="todayRow2">-2</div>
    <div class="thruRow2">F</div>
    <div class="totalRow2">-7</div>
</div>
<div class="studentRow" ref="1000">
    <div class="favRow1" ref="1000">click</div>
    <div class="positionRow1">1</div>
    <div class="studentRow1">Name A</div>
    <div class="todayRow1">-3</div>
    <div class="thruRow1">F</div>
    <div class="totalRow1">-9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ?????? What you trying to say.

Comment: You can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929519/dynamically-arranging-divs-using-jquery/929607#929607

Comment: Thanks @navand.In the example, the array is created by getting the simple input text value. The prefix is also limited only one. I'll try to create an array loop through and get the positionRow text from the favoritesList.