# Rearrange child repeaters within a parent repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a set of nested repeaters with a structure like this:

```
Repeater A
     Repeater A-1
     Repeater A-2
     Repeater A-3
Repeater B
     Repeater B-1
     Repeater B-2
     Repeater B-3
```

I want to dynamically rearrange the child repeaters within the parent repeater at run-time.  For example, based on a user configuration, I might want to change the order of Repeater A's children to be 2,3,1.  I'm open to either a server or client-side solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue for the client side jquery approach. This will avoid any postbacks, which are so 1990's these days. If you are able to wrap your repeater content into some sort of container element and supply them with Id attributes you could write a very reusable JQ function the does the rearranging for you.

Asp.net Code: (you already have something similar)

```
<asp:Repeater DataSource="<%#source%>" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div id="containerA">
      <asp:Repeater DataSource="<%#Container.DataItem%>" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <div id="A-<%# Bind("Count") %>"><%#SomeEvaluatedMethod()%></td>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<div id="containerA">
   <div id="A1">some text</div>
   <div id="A2">some text</div>
   <div id="A3">some text</div>
</div>
```

To Arrange divs via Jquery:

To avoid re-inventing the wheel, take a look at these examples, there are a couple working examples here. Choose what makes the most sense for you and your project.

[Dynamically arranging divs using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929519/dynamically-arranging-divs-using-jquery)

Comment: Thanks - the repeaters are already wrapped in container DIVs, which I could certainly manipulate from jQuery.

Comment: just updated, and provided a link that has some really nice examples.

Comment: The answer you linked to is perfect.  Thanks for this - it's a huge help.