# How to move an absolutely positioned <div> to 20px above a specific DOM event/element?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery.

How to deal with it easily?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158070/jquery-how-to-position-one-element-relative-to-another

Comment: i'd love to move a div 20px above a specific dom event.. lemme know when you find out

Comment: @womp ,it's half of my question.What about move by event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var offset = $(<dom-element>).offset();
$(<div>).css({ top: (offset.top - $(<div>).height() - 20) + "px",
               left: offset.left });
```

For more information, check out the [CSS documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS) of jQuery.

Also, for most events you can call `event.target` to get the element generating event.

To get current mouse position use `event.pageX` and `event.pageY`.  Note that the event must come from a mouse action: `onmousemove`, `onmouseup`, `onmousedown`, `onclick`, etc...

Comment: How to do it according to event?

Comment: Where is the event coming from?  In general you can call `event.target` to get DOM node generating the event.

Comment: event has information about where the click happens,it's not the same as DOM node position.

Comment: Replace the above `$(<dom-element>).offset()` with `$(event.target).offset()`

Comment: To get the current mouse position, you can use `event.pageX` and `event.pageY`.

Answer (score 1):

use offset();

var offset = $('#elem1').offset();
$('#elem2').css('top', offset.top );

http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset