# jQuery: position element next to another and fix it there

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to position ElementA next to ElementB like specified here:
[How to position one element relative to another with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158070/jquery-how-to-position-one-element-relative-to-another)

with the only difference being that I want ElementA to move around with ElementB if ElementB is moved.

Is it possible to somehow fix a certain element's position to another? It's not feasible for me to recalculate ElementA's position every time ElementB is moved.

**UPDATE**

In my situation, ElementB was a `td` element. Apparently, `td` elements can't be relatively positioned, which was why ElementA wasn't moving with ElementB. An easy fix for this was simply adding a relatively positioned `div` inside ElementB and then placed ElementA in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Look here for a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/jPUbh/

Change your html to this:

```
<div id="placeholder" style="position:relative">
    <div id="placeholder-text">Hover over me to show the menu here</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; display: none; top: 20px; left: 0px" id="menu">
       <!-- menu stuff in here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

and your JS to this:

```
$("#placeholder-text").mouseover(showMenu);

var showMenu = function(ev) {
  $("#menu").show();
}
```

When the parent element (int this case div#placeholder) is set to relative, the block level elements inside it that are set to absolute will be positioned relative to the parent. So change the top and left properties of the div#menu to fit your needs. Now if div#placeholder moves then div#menu moves with it.

And your JS is much cleaner with some CSS!

Also the ids are totally generic, change them as you wish :-) And update the JS if you change them in html!

Comment: Hmm, it's not working. in my case, ElementA is appended to ElementB via javascript. Could this have any effect on how ElementA is positioned?

Comment: Oh and ElementB is also a <td>

Comment: OMG! Thanks!  I've +1'ed you for this!  I had the 'position:' set to everything I could think of for my 'attached' object but never thought to set the parent object to 'relative'... That did the trick!  THANK YOU SO MUCH! :D

Answer (score 2):

If you make *ElementA* a child of *ElementB* then that is possible, it doesn't have to be "inside" it to be a child, you can position the element relative to the parent, using negative coordinates to take it outside.  Then moving *ElementB* should reposition the child too.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/sEGZD/

Comment: @bnieland: Added a demonstration, all DIVs are moveable, the parent moves the lot.