# Use jQuery to position element relative to another that is not the parent

Tags: jquery

If you look here: http://dev.driz.co.uk/tips/ You will see I am experimenting with some Facebook ripoff tooltips.

What I'm trying to learn is how to position the tip relative to another object. So for example if a user hovered the red box it would show the relevant tooltip but in relation to the object with the arrow pointing at the redbox. I've thought about using the outerWidth and height or even the `position()` method. but not sure how I would use it. Also need to position the arrow in relation as well such as where on the box and move it up and down if the user scrolls the page ie. moves the element.

If someone can provide some examples that'd be awesome.

**NOTE I'm not trying to do the hover bit at the moment just trying to get the tip to position itself in relation to the other object.**

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: You could use the current mouse position if you want to show the tooltip only when the mouse is over the redbox

Comment: I'm not trying to do the hover! I'm trying to position it relation to the other object.

Comment: Look here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158070/jquery-how-to-position-one-element-relative-to-another)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var top = $("#link").offset().top;
top += $("#link").height();
var left = $("#link").offset().left;
$("#tip").css({
    top: top+"px",
    left: left + "px"
});
```

This code positions `#tip` relative to the `#link`. It's very likely that you want to show `#tip` below `#link`, hence `top += $("#link").height();`.

Comment: It's not a parent and child element! Please read question title ;)

Comment: As edited, this looks correct. The general technique is that you will use $("#link").offset() to get the position of the red box relative to the document, then use those coordinates, along with either absolute or fixed positioning, as the basis for the coordinates of $("#tip").

Comment: dgvid is right. `offset()` is used instead of `position()`, because the second function returns the offset relative to the parent, rather than the root.

Comment: Try again, I accidentally used `offset("top")` instead of `offset().top`