# jQuery Position Element next to each other on mouse over - with fixing of scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar, onmouseover

So I fiddled with this
[jsFiddle of mouseover together with absolute positioning divs](http://jsfiddle.net/YpcSe/1/)

The outcome is undesired. The code is based on [jquery how to position one element relative to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158070/jquery-how-to-position-one-element-relative-to-another)
But the code is not working as expected. I can figure out how to reposition the offset depending on the absolute positioning (e.g. substract offset of header). But what I have trouble with is the scrolling positioning. As soon as you start scrolling the position is wrong. Does someone know a solution of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hate to answer my own questions but see here:
[working solution with jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/YpcSe/4/)

basically the problem was that the element was inserted at the wrong location. The offset somehow did not relate correctly to the page with scrollbars. This can be fixed by adding the element on the parent form (in case you wanna make some buttons visible for example). Or the `<body>`

It fixes as well a problem with overlapping elements I had. Just imagine you have an fixed positioned element E1 and an absolute positioned element E2. One is the left menu, E2 is the content. When you want to make visible / show an element when you mouseover over a e.g. div in the E2 content and want it to overlap over the left menu E1 then you need to make sure that the div is not in the content, since it seems you cannot overlap into a sibling of E2 which is positioned fixed.

Comment: I've updated the answer for the original question you referenced, and it should now handle your case as well :)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the `offset().top` value changes in jQuery when you scroll the document. Instead, simply use the standard HTML element properties `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop`:

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/YpcSe/2/

Code:

```
$("#m1").mouseover( function(){
    $("#o1").css({ "left": this.offsetLeft, "top":this.offsetTop }).show();
})
.mouseout( function(){
    $("#o1").hide();
});



$("#m2").mouseover( function(){
   $("#o2").css({ "left": this.offsetLeft, "top":this.offsetTop }).show();
})
.mouseout( function(){
    $("#o2").hide();
});
```

Comment: By the way, examples like this are always a nice opportunity to reflect on when jQuery is actually necessary (i.e. using offsetLeft rather than jquery's offset function). Another example is using this.className rather than $(this).attr('class')...

Comment: i have to correct myself: this is not working. The plain old javascript offsetTop function gives me a completely wrong position which was related to some different parent element as soon as I use it in a bit more complex webpage.

Comment: Then please post your code, or create a fiddle that shows this.

Comment: I would love to, but I already spent too much time on this issue and am never gonna get up-votes whatsoever. I post the solution which fixes the problems (and additional ones)

Comment: i'll have to look at it again. But only when i get time... - what looks promising is that it does not have the bug of floating you see in my example. E.g. you hover over the second red thing, then scroll - the text will scroll a bit with the scroll before disappearing.