# Scroll Window to a div element using Jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

How to apply `scrollTop` feature to currently clicked element.I would like to create a sidebar shows in following application

http://catalog.offersdb.com/

Tried as follows

http://jsfiddle.net/y4dye/

Please help... Thanks in advance

Comment: It will not work because offset keep changing when user clicks. Read this for further information about relative positioning. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158070/jquery-how-to-position-one-element-relative-to-another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: http://jsfiddle.net/y4dye/4/

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(".view_more").click(function() {
    $('#sidebar').animate({
        scrollTop: ($(this).position().top + $("#sidebar").scrollTop())
    }, 'slow');
});​
```