# jQuery UI positioning via another element

Tags: jquery-ui

Everyone made such short work of my first question, now I'm stumped with another issue.

This is mostly a jQuery problem I'm suspecting, though because it is being echoed according to some MySQL variables, it's getting very confusing. I've found jQueryUI came recommended from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2781557/1311697), but this particular code isn't working at all for me.

I've tried to get as much of the PHP and MySQL out of this example by just looking at the source. The variables appear to be working properly.

In the following example, I'm attempting to move the DIV with ID of res10 directly over the SPAN with ID 100019. The jQueryUI scripts are set to load. The 
 tags are just there to demonstrate that they are in two separate locations; once this is functioning, the SPAN should be able to be nearly anywhere.

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function() {

$("#res10").position({
    my:        "left top",
    at:        "left bottom",
    of:        $("#100019"), //I also tried just "#100019" and that didn't work.
    collision: "fit"
})

});

</script>   
<span id="151520"> [a spacer gif, but nothing else] </span>
<br /><br />
<div class="resContainer res10" id="res10">Information and Such</div>
```

Note that the resContainer class's CSS does not position the object AT ALL, not even a default position: attribute.

Edit: It occurs to me that one might ask 'why are you doing this?' because just using the hard code makes it look like it could all be achieved with CSS alone. Without getting into a bunch of details on the why, just know it won't work like that.

If jQuery can achieve the same thing by getting offset() variables and setting CSS, that's great, but I tried a bunch and it didn't work, in fact, I got the same output I get when using this, which is that all the DIVs generated by the PHP/MySQL (not shown) appear on top of eachother, at the bottom of the screen below everything else where the PHP script is called.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I am not sure exactly how it happened, but I've solved my own problem. Maybe a syntax error or the wrong UI loading, but here's what I ended up using that's working perfectly for me.

```
// - Can be placed anywhere, as long as it occurs before the SPAN it's adjusting
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#resContainer3").position({
    "my": "right top",
    "at": "right top",
    "of": $("#100013"),
    "offset": "-3 7"
});
});
</script>

<span class=resContainer id=resContainer3></span>
```

Hope this helps anyone who happens to have the same issue as myself!