# Positioning an element relative to another element

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, position, element

I've two labels in my form. The second one is just below the first one. On listbox index change both of them are filled with text, and both of them have MaximumSize property set so that they could grow only vertically. When the upper label is filled with long enough string, it's content is overlaid over the 2nd label.

Is there any simple way to bind element's position to the height of another element? Or should I just change position based on height of chosen element programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: How to position one element relative to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158070/jquery-how-to-position-one-element-relative-to-another)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides programatically reacting to SizeChanged, you could also use a FlowLayoutPanel...

Comment: Simple indeed. It's kinda strange I didn't run into FlowLayoutPanel while searching for suitable solution before.