# How can I add a popup menu next to a link on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm writing an extension that adds to an existing site so I can't modify the HTML directly. Basically there is a series of links contained in a single div separated only by spaces. I am trying to use jquery to add a link of my own at an arbitrary location in this series and open a small menu immediately next to the link, like a right click context menu. When the link/menu hover focus is gone it should disappear.

I can handle the jquery for the actual behavior but I'm a little concerned about where in the document I should be placing the html for this menu. Should it be at the end of the body? Just before/after the link? And then when I do hover over the link how do I get the correct positioning for this element? I've found examples but they all use lists. I just need a menu on link hover that appears *next to the link*.

In short, my main concern is about how to position the popup div correctly beside the link. Secondary to that is how to keep the menu open when I try to hover over it instead of the link.

This is how far I can get before I'm not sure what to do : http://jsfiddle.net/jRpyp/

```
$(".menu a").filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "Link 3"; }).after(" | <a href=\"#\" id=\"popup-link\">My text</a> | ");
$("#popup").toggle();
$("#popup-link").hover(
    function(e)
    {
        $("#popup").show();
    },
    function(e)
    {
        $("#popup").fadeOut("slow");
    });
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a> | <a href="#">Link 2</a> | <a href="#">Link 3</a> | <a href="#">Link 4</a> <br />
    <a href="#">More links</a> | <a href="#">More links</a> | <a href="#">More links</a> | <a href="#">More links</a>
</div>
<div id="popup">
    <ul>
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the `filter` function needed for?

Comment: To select a link based on its text. I'm aware I could also use :eq() or :nth-child().

Comment: So you only want it for that link?

Comment: Only on the link that I'm adding. It's for custom functionality based on my extension that I don't want to show on a different page or force elsewhere into the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found an answer that works. I'm not sure that it's the best way to go about it so I'll go ahead and leave it open in case someone else can find something better.

First I did some more research and found the jQuery `offset()` function which lets me get the position of the link. From there I set the position of the div to the link. I had some issues with the hover being too picky about where the mouse was, so I created a large div that goes around the link with left padding so that the link itself wouldn't be hidden while the menu was shown and so that I could have a little bit of wiggle room outside the menu to keep it from disappearing. Changing the positioning and padding of the div will give more flexibility in how far the mouse can move before the menu fades out.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jRpyp/10/).

And here's the code minus html/css:

```
$(".menu a").filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "Link 3"; }).after(" | <a href=\"#\" id=\"popup-link\">My text</a> | ");

var popupPosition = $("#popup-link").offset();
// Edit positioning as needed
//popupPosition.left += $("#popup-link").width();

$("#popup").offset(popupPosition);
$("#popup").css("padding-left", $("#popup-link").width());
$("#popup").toggle();

$("#popup-link").hover(
    function(e)
    {
        $("#popup").show();
    },
    function(e)
    {
        //$("#popup").fadeOut("slow");
    });

$("#popup").hover(
    function(e)
    {
        popupHovering = true;
        $("#popup").show();
    },
    function(e)
    {
        $("#popup").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: I do intend to learn how to make a proper timeout on that popup rather than using goofy div hacks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `#popup` needs to be set to a positioning as `absolute`. This will enable you to position it anywhere on the page, no matter where it appears in the HTML.

This is the basic jQuery you should use <sup>1</sup>

```
function (e) {
    var pos = $(this).position(); // Gets the position of the link
    var width = $(this).outerWidth(); // Gets the width of the link
    $("#popup").css({
        top: pos.top + "px", // Uses the top positioning of the link to put it in the same area
        left: (pos.left + width) + "px" // First puts the menu in the same leftward position of the link, then adds the width to prevent overlap
    }).show();
}
```

This will ensure that no matter where the link is, it will appear close to the link

If you want to add some more space between the link and the menu, simple add `+` and a number

For example

```
left: (pos.left + width + 10) + "px" // Would add 10 extra pixels, so it doesn't look like they are right next to each other
top: (pos.top + 20) + "px" // Adds 20 extra pixels
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jRpyp/5/)

---

<sub>1: Provided by https://stackoverflow.com/a/158176/1470950</sub>

Comment: I add the link through the javascript. I cannot directly modify the HTML of the site I'm using this javascript on.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to make it clearer. Basically I need the popup menu to appear beside the link.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something similiar to this http://jsfiddle.net/jRpyp/4/ updated version of the script?

```
$("#popup").toggle();
$(".menu a").hover(function (e) {

// change selected a-tags css to get a margin

$("#popup").css({
    position: "absolute",
    top: 50 + "px", // based on the position of the selected a-tag
    left: 100 + "px" // based on the position of the selected a-tag
}).show();
},

function (e) {
    $("#popup").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Regarding to one of your questions:

> I can handle the jquery for the actual behavior but I'm a little
>   concerned about where in the document I should be placing the html for
>   this menu. Should it be at the end of the body? Just before/after the
>   link?

It doesn't matter where to place the html, since its only use is to be displayed (on a determined position) within the side. I think people often nest such html at the end of the document, within a div with an id like template (to access it easier with jQuery).

(I hope I got the question right.)