# Appending element to image area map using exact coordinates

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to append a new element to an area map using the coordinates to determine the position of the new element. What I have so far:

```
var count = document.createTextNode("FooBar");
var dspan = document.createElement("span");
dspan.appendChild(count);

var hrefs = document.querySelectorAll("area");

for (var i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
    console.log(hrefs[i].getAttribute('coords'));
    console.log(hrefs[i].getAttribute('href'));
    console.log(hrefs[i].getAttribute('alt'));
    console.log(hrefs[i].parentNode.appendChild(dspan));
}
```

HTML Area map:

```
<map name="spotLightmap-50">
<area alt="Laptops" href="url.com" coords="1,1,357,226" shape="rect" onclick="s_objectID="url.com";return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">
</map>
```

Say for this map, I use have the coords `1,1,357,226`. How can I position the new dspan element within the coordinates of the map element.

Comment: I don't understand the javascript inside your onclick property: `onclick="s_objectID="url.com";return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true"`. You'll need to use single quotes around url.com in order to avoid ending the onclick= string. And then I simply don't understand what `this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true` is supposed to be. Please your code to on jsfiddle.com or similar so that we can see what is working so far.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "within the coordinates of the map element"? You want the new span element to cover the whole map element? Or just be anywhere in there? Or you want a function that positions it relative to a corner of the map? Chances are your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158070/jquery-how-to-position-one-element-relative-to-another

Comment: I would like the new element to be placed anywhere within those coords, and was hoping to get it doen in pure js.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you've used the wrong type of quote characters - `"url.com"` --> `'url.com'`
The first `"` effectively terminates the statement that you use to set the onclick.

Next, I've done no error checking. I've only looked for the first `<area>` tag, I haven't checked that it's actually a rect, as opposed to a poly, which may have fewer or more co-ord pairs.

**Html**

```
<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=6" alt="HTML Map" border="0" usemap="spotLightmap-50"/>
    <map name="spotLightmap-50">
        <area alt="Laptops" href="url.com" coords="50,100,357,226" shape="rect" onclick="s_objectID='url.com';return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">
    </map>
```

**Javascript**

```
window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt);}
function mInit()
{
    var txt = newTxt("Lorus Ipsum");
    var span = newEl('span');
    span.appendChild(txt);

    var map = document.getElementsByName('spotLightmap-50');
    map = map[0];
    var areaTags = map.getElementsByTagName('area');

    var coOrdStr = areaTags[0].getAttribute('coords');
    var coOrds = coOrdStr.split(',');
    var xPos, yPos, width, height;
    xPos = coOrds[0];
    yPos = coOrds[1];
    width = coOrds[2];
    height = coOrds[3];

    //alert("xPos: " + xPos);
    span.style.left = xPos + "px";
    span.style.top = yPos + "px";
    span.style.width = width + "px";
    span.style.height = height + "px";
    span.style.zIndex = 2;
    span.style.position = 'absolute';
    document.body.appendChild(span);
}
```