# Inject a text above a div centered horizontally and vertically

Tags: jquery

I have a div on my page and I would like to superpose a text above this div thanks to jQuery. This text must be  centered horizontally and vertically. I need this to show to the user this zone is allowed to drop a file in it.

```
<div class="dropzone" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: gray">
    Lorem ipsum blah blah... Lorem ipsum blah blah... Lorem ipsum blah blah... Lorem ipsum blah blah... Lorem ipsum blah blah... Lorem ipsum blah blah... 
</div>
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dd2jq/

I have no idea how to proceed to inject a text above my div. I know we have the append jQuery function but no idea how to proceed.

Any help is greathly appreciated.

Comment: Check out the incredibly awesome [`jQuery.position()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/).  It was introduced to jQuery **UI** in version 1.8. It makes positioning things relative to other elements very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it **very** simple by using the new [`jQuery.position()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) function:

```
var $span = $('<span/>').text('Hello, world');
$span.position({ of: $('.dropzone') });
```

It looks really simple here, because the span gets centered by default.

But... The new *position()* function gives you a ton of control over positioning (and it's easy to use).

**Note:**

This function was added to **jQuery UI** in version 1.8.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UPyYh/4/).

Comment: This is really the best solution for my purpose. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help.  I was so happy the day I [found this little gem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2781557/778118)!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bR9YD/)

```
var text = 'Some text here';
var span$ = $('<span></span>').text(text);
var div$ = $('.dropzone');
var position = div$.position();

$('body').append(span$);


span$.css( {position:'absolute', left:position.left + (div$.width() / 2) - (span$.width() / 2)   , top:position.top + (div$.height() / 2) - span$.height() /2, zIndex:10000, background:'#ffffff'});
```

Comment: Check out how the new [`jQuery.position()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) function makes it much easier: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bR9YD/2/). **Note:** You have to add jQuery UI version 1.8 or higher (but it's worth it).

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
$(".dropzone").before("<p>test!</p>");
```