# Position some text behind a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I needed to position some text centered horizontally and vertically relative to a 'dropzone' (a div). It works with this solution: [Inject a text above a div centered horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578749/inject-a-text-above-a-div-centered-horizontally-and-vertically)

The JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UPyYh/4/

```
var $span = $('<span/>').text('Hello, world');
$('body').append($span);
$span.position({ of: $('.dropzone') });
```

Now I need to have this text behind the dropzone. (And I'll set the dropzone to an opacity of .5 for example). I don't know if it is possible but I didn't found a way to do it.

Why doing it? To have my text ('Drop your files here') showed behind the dropzone area to not interfere with the dropzone.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
.dropzone {
background: silver;
height: 300px;
padding: 5px;
border: 2px solid rgb(255, 165, 0);
opacity: 0.8;
}
```

and

```
$span.css('z-index', -1);
```

Or add this CSS rule to `bright`:

```
.bright{
   z-index: -1;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k2EQK/)

Comment: You can also just add the 'z-index' to you .bright css if you want to.

Comment: Thanks. It works here in jsFiddle but in my personal project (which is more complex) as soon as I set the z-index of bright to -1 it disappeared!

Comment: @Bronzato disappeared means that the `div` is under another element. Maybe under the parent of `dropzone`. You have to adjust the z-index of your different elements.