# Get the XY coordinates of a `img` element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an icon `<img src="res/img/b_drop.png" id="drop_1" />`. When this icon is clicked, I need a prompt to appear at some coordinates that I will calculate by the S and Y points of my `#drop_`. What can I do to calculate these two points using jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: How to position one element relative to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158070/jquery-how-to-position-one-element-relative-to-another)

Comment: jQuery info: [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

offset could be what you want

```
$('#drop_1').on('click', function(){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    alert('top - ' + offset.top + "\n left - " + offset.left);
});
```

This will alert the position of the element from the top and left of the document

[jQuery offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Here is a

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jSNAx/)

Answer (score 0):

Relatively parent element:

```
$('#drop_1').position().left // x coord
$('#drop_1').position().top // y coord
```

Relatively page:

```
$('#drop_1').offset().left // x coord
$('#drop_1').offset().top // y coord
```