# Make one html element follow another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have an AngularJS, JS, JQ, HTML5, CSS3 web app. Web interface is supposed to be divided into 2 parts and the first part should be resizable.

I would like to bind location of `<preview>` element from the first part to the location UNDER the top level of second part (location of `"response"` word on image) using jquery. So it looked something like this:

[image]

It should always be under the border line whenever it goes up or down.

Does anyone know how to solve this using JQuery? Every useful answer is highly appreciated and evaluated.

Thank you.

Comment: from where I see it, you just need CSS and HTML to do this... but it's hard to say without seeing any code from you... maybe you could create a jsFiddle for us to see ?

Comment: What you describe sounds a lot like the default layout of elements, can you clarify why just putting the preview element after the one you want it to follow doesn't do what you want? I'm sure it's just an explanation thing.

Comment: It's too complex, because it is tightly bound to our web services.

Comment: @NazarSobchuk: *"It's too complex, because it is tightly bound to our web services."* It's your job to create a [simple enough example](http://sscce.org) that people can help you.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder because the preview element, which resides within the first part, is in the scope of AngularJS controller and must stay there in order to work properly.

Comment: Can you not put it outside the div with `display: block` (if it isn't)?

Comment: @Colandus no, I can't. I just have to make preview element follow border line without changing HTML code.

Comment: For all I know you could use jQuery to position it below it. Something like how it's done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158070

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might not understand the question but you could try creating a container div around all your HTML elements and giving it a float css property.
then you can cut/paste the element you want underneath to outside of your container and giving it the clear both css property

Comment: Well, you see..I have done something similar to this. My whole html code is wrapped with a div, which is resizable (JQuery-ui resizable). And now I want to move one element from my HTML under the border, without directly replacing it's HTML code.