# Positioning an element on hover another element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with CSS "display:none", and I want it to be positioned in a certain way while hovering an image of the class "preview".
I can't use just CSS, because my hidden div involves images which are to be changed depending on what Image from list item you hover.
I've read and tried everything here,
[How to position one element relative to another with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158070/jquery-how-to-position-one-element-relative-to-another)

but nothing works to me.
Here's my HTML:

```
   <div id="content">
        <ul>
           <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="preview" src="images/E46_1.jpg">
                </a>
               <div>Whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever</div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="preview" src="images/E93_1.jpg">
                </a>
               <div>Whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever</div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="preview" src="images/E46_1.jpg">
                </a>
               <div>Whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And my div with CSS "display:none" is a slider.

I think I need a **simple** (not like the ones from the link I posted above) analogue of Javascript's getBoundingClientRect() in JQuery. Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

If you can elaborate, i can make this better, but for the basics, here goes:

here is a combination of both:
http://jsfiddle.net/zc2m9yh1/

jQ:

```
$("#content ul li").hover(function () {
    var src = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
    $(this).children("div").html('<img src="' + src + '">');
}, function () {
    //on mouseout
});
```

css:

```
#content ul li div {
    display: none;
}
#content ul li:hover div {
    display: block;
}
#content ul li img {
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand how it solves the issue. I need my hidden div to appear aside a hovered image (like a tooltip box). In your example it just appends one image below the list.

Comment: You append the element on the dom, and then do a relative position such as fixed, and get the view port position of the element you want it top position to. If you need an example, I can write one up. Anyways, I use to use that method when working with libs like tomatoe.

Comment: @Casey An example would be great, if you can, please.

Comment: oh, now that gives me a better idea of what you need. here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/5fegvgrw/

Answer (score 0):

Here as follows:

```
var pos = $(element to position by).position();

var width = $(this).outerWidth();

//show the element over the placeholder
$("item to position").css({
    position: "absolute",
    top: pos.top + "px",
    left: (pos.left + width) + "px"
}).show();
```

});

A great example working is also here on a fiddle another created. http://jsfiddle.net/wjbuys/QrrpB/

Comment: I can't understand the reason, but it doesn't work to me.
Here's my slider,
http://postimg.org/image/661yeml3t/
but after inserting the code it looks like that
http://postimg.org/image/k0u2gpltd/
And that "slidercut" even doesn't move like it's supposed when hover an image. It's just stuck at the same place and being cut.

Comment: Remember, that this is also based on layout, not what you visually see. An element may seem it is at the bottom left of the screen, but is positioned differently to the actual relative position. Can you post your code on fiddle, and I can take a look at it?

Comment: Somehow Fiddle doesn't show me my Slider div properly as expected in the screenshot #1. But anyway, the principle must be the same.
Here it is
http://jsfiddle.net/hon9yv8e/

Can you please help make that "div" (black box in the left) appear at the right side of the images when hover them. Like a dialog window.