# Position a div relative to another div which is not its parent using CSS

Tags: html, css, position

I'm aware of the `position:relative` and `position:absolute` trick to position a div relative to its parent. But what if the div is not its parent and I want to position it relative to that? I'm trying to implement something along those lines.

I'm also aware of `position:fixed` to fix a div but I'm building a responsive website and I'd like to avoid that. I found a question here which mentions using jQuery to do it: [How to position one element relative to another with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158070/jquery-how-to-position-one-element-relative-to-another) Is jQuery the only way to do it? Can it be done using CSS as well?

I've put up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/19bdpgsf/. In the fiddle, I'm trying to position the `child2` element relative to the `notparentdiv`just like it has been positioned relative to the `parent` div. Is it possible using only css?

Thanks.

Comment: which div you want to position and where

Comment: the child2 div with respect to the notparentdiv just like how it is currently positioned with respect to the parent in the fiddle. I've mentioned that in the question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/19bdpgsf/1/ something like this?

Comment: I don't think it is possible using `position`, perharps [display: flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) could be worth to consider.

Comment: Thanks @JanTuroň Think I'll have to go the jQuery way as flexbox support in IE is abysmal.

Answer (score 4):

Another way if you dont want to use css positions use offset jquery as below to position you div

```js
var nonparent = $('.notParent');
var position = nonparent.offset();
$('.child1').offset({
  top: position.top,
  left: position.left
});
```

```css
.notParent {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
.child2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.child1 {
  background-color: green;
}
.parent {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notParent">
  not parent div
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="parent">
  parent
  <div class="child1">child1</div>
  <div class="child2">
    child2
  </div>
</div>
```

You can position a div inside another div which is not parent with absolute relative positions as below

```css
.notParent {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
.child2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
.child1 {
  background-color: green;
  top: 30px;
}
.parent {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="notParent">
  not parent div
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="parent">
  parent
  <div class="child1">child1</div>
  <div class="child2">
    child2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not like that. You just removed the position:relative already existing in the parent div. I don't want that.

Comment: Nope :). What if I have other divs relative to that parent div? It'll mess up the styles.

Comment: ok i have added one more way to do it with j query offset see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
var position = document.getElementById("relative");
document.getElementById("").appendChild(position);
```

maybe use something like this to move the div into the div you want it in?

This will place a div into the desired div, and from there `position:relative;` will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute positioning (relative to the entire body of the page), but other than that I don't think there's any other way than jQuery.

Comment: But in my example, position:relative is already applied to the parent div. It'll just ignore the body's position:relative.