# Position element relative to another element not its parent

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-position

Is it possible to make a positioned element relative to another element which isn't currently its parent? Example:

```
<div class="want-to-be-parent">
<div class="current-parent">
<div class="element-to-position"><!---content---></div>
</div>
</div>
```

So in this instance, I want to absolutely position 'element-to-position' at the top left of 'want-to-be-parent' but its currently relatively positioned inside 'current-parent'.

EDIT - Assume that all three of these elements have 'position: relative' and that I have no control over that. I want to absolutely position 'element-to-position' and have it be absolutely positioned relative to 'want-to-be-parent' and not to 'current-parent'. I have to do this dynamically as there is no other way.

Comment: See this past question, related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065135/position-a-div-relative-to-another-div-which-is-not-its-parent-using-css

Answer (score 4):

Set **want-to-be-parent** to `position:relative;` and set **current-parent** to `position:static;`

When you use `position:absolute` on an element it will position relative to the first parent with non-static position, preferably relative position to avoid messing the layout.

Your code should look something like this:

```css
.want-to-be-parent {
  position:relative;
  padding:40px;
  border:1px solid;
  
}

.current-parent{
  padding:40px;
  border:1px solid;
}

.element-to-position {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  padding:10px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="want-to-be-parent">
want to be parent
  <div class="current-parent">
  curent parent
    <div class="element-to-position">
      element
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even more interesting when closing the want-to-be-parent immediately, making it a sibling of current-parent. Still works like a charm.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I know how to do this with css, obviously, but I don't want to change anything about those divs or their positioning, I just want to dynamically take the 'element-to-position' from where it is and position it absolutely inside the 'want-to-be-parent'.

Comment: @Jerpl that is exactly what i have done using css .. i didn't change the html .. maybe you should edit your question to make it more clear :)

Comment: The nearest positioned ancestor doesn't need to be `position: relative`. It can be *any* positioning value except `static`. Of course, `relative` makes the most sense since it doesn't disturb the layout.