# JQuery Updated Positioning From 1.9.1

Tags: jquery

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158070/how-to-position-one-element-relative-to-another-with-jquery) with a documented link to the JQuery UI page.  I'm using a derivative of their example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3xw5zgfa/) and I don't show the three first divs for later versions of JQuery, with the fourth being intentionally excluded.  According to JQuery's documenation, this was added in *version 1.8* as well as stating that *this is a standalone jQuery plugin and has no dependencies on other jQuery UI components*.

In JQuery 1.9.1, this runs without issue.  However, in later versions, it doesn't.  Is there an updated way to position elements?

```
$("#position1").position({
  my: "center",
  at: "center",
  of: "#targetElement"
});

$("#position2").position({
  my: "left top",
  at: "left top",
  of: "#targetElement"
});

$("#position3").position({
  my: "right center",
  at: "right bottom",
  of: "#targetElement"
});

/// position4 is intentionally not present
```

Is there an updated way to do this, or should I only reference this version for the appropriate page?

Comment: have you checked compatibility of the jQuery UI version you are using? Any errors thrown?

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah, in the linked fidde - https://jsfiddle.net/3xw5zgfa/ - it appears to be using the latest jQuery library and the UI elements.  The next version down, ```3.1.1 Slim``` is the same.

Comment: suggest you search their bug tracker