# position absolute in relative hide overflow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a scrollable dropdown in a scrollable div

To manage dropdown, I'm using `position:relative` on the container and `position:absolute`
on the content, but if the dropdown content is higher than the container, or start at the end of the scrollable content, it will be displayed below, and maybe hiden by the overflow
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfluJ.png)

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iouBQ.png)

I'm looking for a way to display this dropdown outside/over the parent div, like a native select do.

I have something like this

```
+------------------------+
|   other                |
|   show                 |
|   +---------------+    |
|   | Content which |    |
|   | expands over  |    |
+------------------------+
```

... but I want something like this (thanks for the illustration :) ) :

```
+------------------------+
|   other                |
|   show                 |
|   +---------------+    |
|   | Content which |    |
|   | expands over  |    |
+---| the parent.   |----+
    +---------------+
```

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do https://codepen.io/spoissonnierAz/pen/LYWOarx

HTML

```
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="data">other</div>
      <div  class="data">
        <div id="show1" onclick="$('#dropdown-content1').show();$('#show1').hide();$('#hide1').show()">show</div>
        <div id="hide1" onclick="$('#dropdown-content1').hide();$('#show1').show();$('#hide1').hide()">hide</div>
        <ul id="dropdown-content1" class="dropdown-content">
          <li>data</li>
          ...
          <li>data end</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="data">other</div>
      ...
      <div class="data">other</div>
      <div  class="data">
        <div id="show2" onclick="$('#dropdown-content2').show();$('#show2').hide();$('#hide2').show()">show</div>
        <div id="hide2" onclick="$('#dropdown-content2').hide();$('#show2').show();$('#hide2').hide()">hide</div>
        <ul id="dropdown-content2" class="dropdown-content">
          <li>data</li>
          ...
          <li>data</li>
          <li>data end</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="data">other</div>
      <div class="data">
        <select>
          <option>data</option>
          ....
          <option>data</option>
          <option>data end</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="data">other</div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
  overflow: auto;
}

.data {
  position:relative;
}

.dropdown-content  {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height:100px;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index:50;
}

.dropdown-content > li {
  display: block;
}

#hide1,#hide2 {
  display: none
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Greetings, paste some code in a snippet and maybe someone will find the issue to help.

Comment: Ok! I see you pasted the code from the code pen you shared earlier.. jeje. But why isn't it working for YOU? the context defines the outcome.

Comment: The content of the dropdown is displayed inside the parent div and hide because of the div height. I'm looking for a way, something like z-index, to display the dropdown above, like the native select input. but I don't know if it's posible ^^

Comment: I'm not following either, in the codepen I see you have another dropdown inside the first, but I'm able to see the whole content, can you clarify your issue futher?

Comment: I want the content of the dropdown ouside de parent div, like the illustration posted by @PeterKerbs

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have this...

```
    +------------------------+
    |   other                |
    |   show                 |
    |   +---------------+    |
    |   | Content which |    |
    |   | expands over  |    |
    +------------------------+
```

... but you want this:

```
    +------------------------+
    |   other                |
    |   show                 |
    |   +---------------+    |
    |   | Content which |    |
    |   | expands over  |    |
    +---| the parent.   |----+
        +---------------+
```

You can position the container with additional information using `.position()` and `.offset()` or use `.css()` directly, which ever works for you.
See stackoverflow search results for "jquery position element relative to another" or similar.
One example here: [How to position one element relative to another with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/158176/10441671)

- [jQuery offset](https://api.jquery.com/offset/)
- [jQuery position](https://api.jquery.com/position/)
- [jQuery css](https://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Thanks for the illustration, it's exactly what I want. I will take a look for other post with keywords you mentioned